# Is removing Cloud Function will automatically delete Artifacts container images from Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

If I delete cloud function, will it free some space in my cloud storage by deleting all container images of this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Function stores the image built from your function's source code using Container Registry by default. If you delete the Cloud Function, related build artifacts in Cloud Storage and Container Registry will also be automatically deleted.

For more information, see this official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/building).